# NUnit in vs2012 reusing app.config when i click "Run All Tests" on multiple project solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, nunit

I have a visual studio 2012 solution with 2 projects projA and projB, and 2 test projects projA_test and projB_test (using NUnit).  ProjA and ProjB both have their own app.config with their own appsettings key/value pairs.  When I click the run all tests the projA unit-tests are ran followed by the projB unit-tests.  But some of the projB unit tests are failing because of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings has only the values from the app.config from projA!  Is this normal behaviour or do I have some configuration setting messed up?

**Edit**.
A point I forgot to mention is that TeamCity (our CI server) does not fail the tests. So my local unit-test runner seems to be doing something weird..

Answer (score 1):

For each of your unit tests you can just set the values for the `ConfigurationManager` as such.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourKey"] = YourValue;
```

If you do this before you objects that require those values they will work just fine.  If they values are for multiple test you can do it in the testfixture setup method.

### Detailed Example

**Class:**

```
public class SomeClass
{
    #region Properties

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    #endregion Properites

    #region Constructors

    public SomeClass()
    {
        Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatValue"];
    }

    #endregion Constructors
}
```

**Test:**  I know this is MSTest/FluentAssertion but concept should work the same

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Example()
    {
        #region Arrange

        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatValue"] = "Batman";

        #endregion Arrange

        #region Act

        var someClass = new SomeClass();

        #endregion Act

        #region Assert

        someClass.Should().NotBeNull();
        someClass.Should().BeOfType<SomeClass>();
        someClass.Value.Should().BeEquivalentTo("Batman");

        #endregion Assert
    }
```

This test passes in the example I just made and has no app.config file available. A unit test shouldn't be dependent on an app.config otherwise you start creepying from unit test to integration testing.

A note that ConnectionStrings are a little different. You would add those to the `ConfigurationManager` as such:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("Name", "ConnectionString"));
```

Comment: The only problem I have is we have > 10,000 tests that are already written like this.  The other point I forgot to mention is that TeamCity (our CI server) does not fail the tests.  So my local unit-test runner seems to be doing something weird..